# Migrating mail to a new server using OfflineIMAP - dot folders not copied

Tags: imap, migration, offlineimap

I am trying to migrate mails from a server to a new server using OfflineIMAP.

My config looks like:

```
[general]
accounts = TestAccount
ui = noninteractive.Basic

[Account TestAccount]
localrepository = TestAccountSource
remoterepository = TestAccountDestination
maxsyncaccounts = 3
maxconnections = 3

[Repository TestAccountSource]
type = IMAP
remotehost = localhost
remoteuser = test@example.com
remotepass = password

[Repository TestAccountDestination]
type = IMAP
remotehost = new.machine.com
remoteuser = test@example.com
remotepass = password
ssl = yes
```

When I run this on the "old" server the syncing starts and mails are being copied. However directories are not being copied to the new machine:

```
offlineimap -c /path/to/my/config
```

The original directory looks like:

```
Chats
Contacts
courierimapkeywords
courierimapsubscribed
courierimapuiddb
cur
Drafts
Emailed Contacts
INBOX
Junk
new
Notes
Sent
tmp
.Subdir
.Subdir.SubSubdir1
.Subdir.SubSubdir2
.Subdir.SubSubdir3
.Subdir.SubSubdir4
```

All mails in the inbox are correctly synced, but the directory `.SubDir` (including subdirs of this) never end up on the new mailserver.

P.S. Old mailserver uses courier, new mailserver uses Zimbra.